# Hard Drive Light Emulator

Tags: laptop, hard-drive, notification-area, dell-inspiron, led

I've just got a new Dell Inspiron, and I'm a little disconcerted without the reassurance of a flashing hard drive light, especially with long installs.  Is there something that can reveal HDD activity onscreen, e.g. in the system tray?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try [HDDPerf](http://hddperf.sourceforge.net/), which is dedicated to showing more details about the moments when the HDD is heavily used.

[image: HDDPerf1]  [image: HDDPerf2] [image: HDDPerf3]

---

[DiskMon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896646.aspx) from Sysinternals can also be minimized to systray and act like a replacement HDD activity light.

[image: DiskMon]

*DiskMon and HDDPerf are both freeware.*

Comment: DiskMon is a little outdated; it has been replaced with ProcMon.

Comment: @grawity - But ProcMon doesn't minimize to tray, and thus doesn't answer this particular question (or I missed the option)

Answer (score 0):

> [HDDLed Indicator](http://www.hddled.com/) shows real-time
>   read and write operations on hard disk
>   drive as small blinking indicators.
>   Features:
>
> - Monitor multiple hard drives.
> - Monitor multiple logical discs.
> - All-in-one mode - single indicator for all drives.
> - Use keyboard ScrollLock led to indicate activity.
> - Use system tray to indicate activity.
> - Separate read and write operations.

*Free to try, 20 bucks to buy.*

Comment: $20 for a little blinking light? overpriced IMO.